# Map one directory path to another in PHPStorm

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm

I'm using JetBrains PHPStorm with Vagrant. The host OS (where PHPStorm runs) is Windows, while the guest OS Vagrant sets up is Ubuntu Linux. The app resides at `/var/www/` in the VM, but on the host that code is at `C:\code\`.

Therefore, in PHPStorm, I get warnings about unresolved directories, when in fact, the path is correct, and can be mapped directly to `C:\code`.

[image]

How can I tell PHPStorm that paths in the code that start with `/var/www/` in my project actually map to `C:\code\`? I'd like path inspections to work again.

Comment: You can setup path mappings here: File | Settings | PHP | Server (add server and enable "use path mappings").

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment. Don't the path mappings in "File | Settings | PHP | Server" control the way remote debugging path mapping works, and not the way the editor resolves paths itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a solution to this, but I thought I would post an answer, as I've since decided this isn't a great way to build include paths in the first place.

I came across a much better approach when reading through the Symfony framework (and Composer's generated autoloader):

```
<?php
// autoload.php @generated by Composer
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInitd1d12712f9bc55fdf8d19536f1f9dd88::getLoader();
```

Here, the PHP magic constant `__DIR__` is used as a starting point for the path. From the [magic constant manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

> `__DIR__` The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`. This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

There are a number of benefits to this approach:

- It's portable - it will work on any operating system that PHP will run on
- It's flexible/dynamic - you can move your files around and the `__DIR__` constant will reflect the new path without any code changes.
- It's familiar - other developers are more likely to recognise this approach, as it uses a native language feature, and they are likely to have come across it before.